# How to make bootstrap dropdown open initially and can't be closed thereafter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know it's hard to provide the code for my question but I would like to know how to make Bootstrap dropdown menu can't be closed (remain open) after it has been opened by default?

Thank you

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: Whichever version sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use 2 functions one `onclick` `dropdown` and one `onclick` `body`
use  `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent closing...

```js
var flag=true;
$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function(e) {
  if (!flag)
     e.stopPropagation();
  else
     flag=false;
});
$(document).on('click', ':not(.dropdown)', function(e) {
  if ($(this).closest('.dropdown').length == 0) {
      e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help!

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

This solution stops propagation on the Bootstrap hide (hide.bs.dropdown) event, which stops it from continuing on to the hidden (hidden.bs.dropdown) event. You may read more into it here: http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

I personally prefer this way also because it uses the built in Bootstrap dropdown events, which could be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events

```js
$(function () {
  $('.dropdown.keep-open').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function () {
      $(this).data('closable', false);
    },
    "click": function (event) {
      $(this).data('closable', false);
    },
    "hide.bs.dropdown": function (event) {
      temp = $(this).data('closable');
      $(this).data('closable', true);
      return temp;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h3>Default behaviour</h3>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr/>
<h3>Preventing bootstrap dropdown from closing on click</h3>
<div class="dropdown keep-open">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I believe this should be a more proper solution, as stopping propagation on the click event might sometimes cause issues later on in development. You may read more into it here: [http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)